# Dynamic Property setter c#

Tags: c#

Hi guys I am trying to generate a delegate at runtime using Dynamic Methods and the ILGenerator to invoke the Setter of a property on an object.....

```
private static GenericIntSetter CreateIntSetMethod(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        MethodInfo setMethod = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod();

        if (setMethod == null)
            return null;

        Type[] arguments = new Type[2];

        arguments[0] = typeof(Person);
        arguments[1] = typeof(int);

        DynamicMethod setter = new DynamicMethod(
             String.Concat("_Set", propertyInfo.Name, "_"),
             typeof(void), arguments, propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
        ILGenerator generator = setter.GetILGenerator();
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass)
        {
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        }
        else
        {
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        }

        generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, setMethod, null);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (GenericIntSetter)setter.CreateDelegate(typeof(GenericIntSetter));
    }
```

When I call this method and I invoke the delete I get a corrupt memory error, any ideas?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why are you doing this?

Comment: Have you considered using [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) for this?

Comment: With the advent of expression trees, this should really be unnecessary unless you're working with old version of C#.

Comment: The code you are emitting does not make sense. Why are you casting/unboxing? What happens if it is not an `int` property on a `Person` class?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. It's really complicated to do that, but not impossible.

I have a open source project just for that http://mirrormirror.codeplex.com

In http://mirrormirror.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66562#869731 you will find the code for all the emit I need to do. It should be easy to find the setter implementation.

Hope it helps

Comment: Interesting project. How does it differ from [Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Have no idea, I didn't know it. From the API perspective, MirrorMirror tries to keep things simple.